# xml.etree.ElementTree: OSError: [Errno 22] when parsing multiple files

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse multiple files (paths listed in a file, one in each line) using the ElementTree.parse as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
file_list = open('datasets\files.txt','r')
for filename in file_list:
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
```

If my files.txt has only one line, the program runs and data is parsed. If I have more than one lines, I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'datasets/data1.xml'
```

Example content of the files.txt is:

```
datasets/data1.xml
datasets/data2.xml
```

Removing either line will make the program work correctly. But when I have both I get the error.
My thoughts were maybe I would have to set `tree = None` to fix it, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `\n` newline character that was causing issues. Had to `strip()` the `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will fix

```
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
file_list = open('datasets\files.txt','r')
for filename in file_list:
    tree = ET.parse(io.StringIO(filename.text))
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing and how it will fix the problem.

Comment: if ElementTree can not parse xml document about non-Unicode issues, StringIO handles it, by keeping string in memory it handles unicode, this will cover encoding problem. Additionally, I added .text after filename. we need to get text attr. from XML to parse it first. it woks on me python 3.6